# C# structure include byte array and long value

Tags: c#, struct, byte

This is My Code to user a long variable with it bytes, but when program runs, Exception Happens and show these:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeLoadException' occurred in Test.exe

Additional information: Could not load type 'Test.MyU32' from assembly 'Test, 
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' because it contains an 
object field at offset 0 that is incorrectly aligned or overlapped by a non-object 
field.

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct MyU32
{
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] Bytes;
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public long Value;
}
```

Please help me how to handle it!

Comment: What's IMAGE_DATA_DIRECTORY ?

Comment: Could it be because the size needs to be 8bytes for Long values?

Comment: Why oh why? A union of a reference and and a 64 bit int called `MyU32`. If you tell us what this code is supposed to achieve we might be able to tell you a more appropriate solution.

Comment: I want to read 4 bytes from a byte buffer, calculate the 32bit value of the content, replace it into the byte buffer.

Comment: `long` is always 64 bits in C#. using `int` or `uint` if you want 32 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Your code case doesn't work because you're overlapping a reference and a value type(a 64 bit int). You can overlap different value types and different references, but you can't mix them.

But even when they work, such low level hacks are usually a bad idea in C#. I recommend using properties which do the transformation instead of low level unions.

Perhaps what you actually want is:

```
internal static class ByteIntegerConverter
{
    public static UInt32 LoadLittleEndian32(byte[] buf, int offset)
    {
        return
            (UInt32)(buf[offset + 0])
        | (((UInt32)(buf[offset + 1])) << 8)
        | (((UInt32)(buf[offset + 2])) << 16)
        | (((UInt32)(buf[offset + 3])) << 24);
    }

    public static void StoreLittleEndian32(byte[] buf, int offset, UInt32 value)
    {
        buf[offset + 0] = (byte)value;
        buf[offset + 1] = (byte)(value >> 8);
        buf[offset + 2] = (byte)(value >> 16);
        buf[offset + 3] = (byte)(value >> 24);
    }
}

UInt32 value = ByteIntegerConverter.LoadLittleEndian32(buf, offset);
// do something with `value`
ByteIntegerConverter.StoreLittleEndian32(buf, offset, value);
```

This always uses little endian regardless of the computer's native endianness. If you want native endainness you could check with `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` and use different shift constants if it is big endian.

Comment: Ok , In this case there is no Byte Array to use! I need to have a array that any change in its bytes change the value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not perfectly sure, but I think the problem is caused by the overlap between a value type and a reference type. It should be possible to overlap only *value types*. Because if it was possible to overlap *value types* & *reference types*, you could change the reference directly. For obvious safety reason, it's not possible.

As `byte[]` is a *reference type* (as all arrays in .NET). You can't have `Value` overlapping `Bytes`.

If you are used to C, your structure (without the explicit layout) would be "similar" to:

```
struct MyU32
{
    byte* Bytes;
    long Value;
}
```

but it is not similar to:

```
struct MyU32
{
    byte Bytes[4];
    long Value;
}
```

Comment: I've specified  "(without the explicit layout)".

Answer (score 0):

I solve my problem

Tanx to All bodies that put time on it.

```
public struct MyU32
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 4)]
    public byte[] Bytes;
    public uint Value
    {
        get { return ((uint)Bytes[0] + Bytes[1] << 8 + Bytes[2] << 16 + Bytes[3] << 24); }
        set 
        { 
            Bytes[0] = (byte)(value & 0xFF);
            Bytes[1] = (byte)(value>>8 & 0xFF);
            Bytes[2] = (byte)(value>>16 & 0xFF);
            Bytes[3] = (byte)(value>>24 & 0xFF);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the `& 0xFF` part is completely useless.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The .NET widening operator between `Int32` and `Byte` will throw an exception if the converted value doesn't fit.  Typecasts in C# do not necessarily use the Framework widening or narrowing operators, but I dislike code that uses typecasts in a fashion that requires the compiler to interpret the semantics differently.

Comment: @supercat 1) I think you mix up widening and narrowing conversions 2) I prefer an `unchecked` block over unnecessary masking. At least in my code, this kind of conversion tends to be in performance critical parts, and I'm not sure if the compiler manages to optimize it out.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Mea culpa--it is narrowing.  My point is that Int32 to Byte conversion defined in .NET will throw an exception for values outside the range 0 to 255.  Even if C# defines a conversion operator which will wrap rather than throw, I do not consider such behavior idiomatic for .NET code.  [For what it's worth, I like .NET but dislike C#. IMHO, there should be a clear delineation between language features and Framework features; C# tries to blur such distinctions with "out" parameters, destructor syntax, the `==` operator, etc., often leading to leaky abstractions].

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Incidentally, I dislike many kinds of numeric typecasting.  To my mind, a *typecast* should throw an exception if it does not yield a representation which is unambiguously better than either all others or all but one.  Integer types represent exact values, so (int)12.0 should work, but (int)12.1 should throw [since 12 is not a "representation" of 12.1"].  Conversion from floating-point values to integers should be easy, but should be a method rather than a "typecast" in any case that requires rounding.  Likewise with extraction of low-order parts of integral quantities.

Comment: @supercat `conv.ovf.u1` throws and `conv.u1` does not. So I don't see how why throwing would be more idiomatic in .net. Personally I compile most of my code with checked arithmetic, but for some projects unchecked arithmetic is really nice.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: Given `Decimal d;` how would something like `(int)d` be processed?  Would such processing be aware of checked or unchecked context?  I agree that unchecked arithmetic is often useful (I wish vb.net had a means of doing it), but don't think typecasting to byte is the "proper" way of doing a wrapping conversion.  I'd rather the framework include a family of `Byte.Wrap(x)` methods for integral source types (along with `Byte.Floor(x)`, `Byte.FloorWrap(x)`, `Byte.Round(x)`, etc. for FP source types).